# Contact form 7 "from" field using sender email or site email?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I was wondering if it is alright to use the sender email to feed the form field?

I've seen other recommend using the site email instead or even email that isn't valid at all, but it doesn't make sense to me though.

For example if the sender name is `James` and his email is `james@gmail.com`, shouldn't his email be used instead of the some other email?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is alright to use your sender email, it is actually better to avoid spam filters sometimes.

But you have to change wordpress standard wp_mail() to make it work:

If your website is `www.example.com` and your sender email is `vincent123@hotmail.com` emails will not be sent, because you have to use a sender email from the same domain, it means `vincent123@example.com`.

To solve this use a plugin like [WP MAIL SMTP](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) it allows you to use SMTP and send your emails using `vincent123@hotmail.com`.